# How can get the data of duplicate tags as comma separated value of xml in sql server using sp_xml_preparedocument?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2012

```
DECLARE @idoc int  
DECLARE @doc varchar(1000)  
SET @doc =' <Questions>  <Question>
          <QuestionCode>IFG_PG_P</QuestionCode>
          <QuestionText>Plate Glass Coverage (Y/N)</QuestionText>
          <FormNumber>CP 19 15</FormNumber>
          <AnswerType>Boolean</AnswerType>
          <ChargeType>Variant</ChargeType>
          <ChargeAmount>3.0000</ChargeAmount>
          <RateBasis>Varies</RateBasis>
          <LOB>Property</LOB>
          <Limits>
            <string>25000</string>
            <string>50000</string>
          </Limits>
          <LimitMin>1</LimitMin>
          <LimitMax>2500</LimitMax>
          <ExposureMin>1</ExposureMin>
          <ExposureMax>2000000000</ExposureMax>

        </Question></Questions>'    
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc    
sELECT   QuestionCode
            ,QuestionText
            ,FormNumber
            ,AnswerType
            ,ChargeType
            ,ChargeAmount
            ,RateBasis
            ,LOB
            ,string             
            ,LimitMin
            ,LimitMax
            ,ExposureMin
            ,ExposureMax
            ,Premium  FROM
       OPENXML (@idoc, 'Questions/Question/Limits',2)
       WITH (
       QuestionCode VARCHAR(100) '../QuestionCode',
                    QuestionText VARCHAR(100) '../QuestionText',
                    FormNumber VARCHAR(100) '../FormNumber',
                    AnswerType VARCHAR(100) '..//AnswerType',
                    ChargeType VARCHAR(100) '../ChargeType',
                    ChargeAmount VARCHAR(100) '../ChargeAmount',
                    RateBasis VARCHAR(100) '../RateBasis',
                    LOB VARCHAR(100) '../LOB',
                    string  varchar(100) '.' ,
                    LimitMin VARCHAR(100) '../LimitMin',
                    LimitMax VARCHAR(100) '../LimitMax',
                    ExposureMin VARCHAR(100) '../ExposureMin',
                    ExposureMax VARCHAR(100) '../ExposureMax',
                    Premium VARCHAR(100) '../Premium'

     )    
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```

Here I have `<Limits>` Tag which has `<string>` duplicate tags. How can i get the data of string in comma separated in sql server. I think `sp_xml_preparedocument` has such facility. Can anyone tell me how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the data in `Limits` as XML and use `nodes()` to shred the `string` values and `for xml` to generate a comma separated value.

```sql
SELECT   QuestionCode
            ,QuestionText
            ,FormNumber
            ,AnswerType
            ,ChargeType
            ,ChargeAmount
            ,RateBasis
            ,LOB
            ,(
             select ','+T.X.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(100)')
             from Limits.nodes('Limits/string') as T(X)
             for xml path(''), type
             ).value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'varchar(max)') as string
            ,LimitMin
            ,LimitMax
            ,ExposureMin
            ,ExposureMax
            ,Premium  FROM
       OPENXML (@idoc, 'Questions/Question',2)
       WITH (
       QuestionCode VARCHAR(100),
       QuestionText VARCHAR(100),
       FormNumber VARCHAR(100),
       AnswerType VARCHAR(100),
       ChargeType VARCHAR(100),
       ChargeAmount VARCHAR(100),
       RateBasis VARCHAR(100),
       LOB VARCHAR(100),
       Limits  xml,
       LimitMin VARCHAR(100),
       LimitMax VARCHAR(100),
       ExposureMin VARCHAR(100),
       ExposureMax VARCHAR(100),
       Premium VARCHAR(100)
     )
```

You could also use the XML datatype for the entire query like this.

```sql
declare @XML xml = @doc

select T.X.value('(QuestionCode/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as QuestionCode,
       T.X.value('(QuestionText/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as QuestionText, 
       T.X.value('(FormNumber/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as FormNumber,
       T.X.value('(AnswerType/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as AnswerType,
       T.X.value('(ChargeType/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as ChargeType,
       T.X.value('(ChargeAmount/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as CarhgeAmount,
       T.X.value('(RateBasis/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as RateBasis,
       T.X.value('(LOB/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as LOB,
       (
       select ','+T2.X.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(100)')
       from T.X.nodes('Limits/string') as T2(X)
       for xml path(''), type
       ).value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'varchar(max)') as string,
       T.X.value('(LimitMin/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as LimitMin,
       T.X.value('(LimitMax/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as LimitMax,
       T.X.value('(ExposureMin/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as ExposureMin,
       T.X.value('(ExposureMax/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as ExposureMax,
       T.X.value('(Premium/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Premium
from @XML.nodes('Questions/Question') as T(X)
```